# PHP regex remove specific part from end of string

Tags: php, regex, string

I have the following string

```
"DJ Antoine, Conor Maynard - Dancing In The Headlights - teledysk, tekst piosenki"
```

and I would like to get only:

```
"DJ Antoine, Conor Maynard - Dancing In The Headlights"
```

I use regex but it not working:

```
^([^\;]+)$ - teledysk, tekst piosenki
```

Comment: split the string between "-" and keep only the first two elements.

Comment: And using regexp? For future

Comment: How are you using `^([^\;]+)$`? `^` and `$` are the start and end of the string, you can't have them in the middle. https://regex101.com/r/nRhNYv/1 (if that string is your regex, your PHP usage is missing from question).

Comment: The function for matching regex in php is `preg_match()`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my two cents :

```
php > $s = "DJ Antoine, Conor Maynard - Dancing In The Headlights - teledysk, tekst piosenki";
php > $new_s = explode('-', $s, -1);
php > echo implode('-', $new_s);
DJ Antoine, Conor Maynard - Dancing In The Headlights
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to remove additional part of string. The regex select additional part and replace it with empty.

```
$str = preg_replace("/-[\w\s,]+$/", "", $str);
```

See result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/Gff6L)